# Replacing a string using sed which has many different characters

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want a variable SERVICE to get replaced by a string $service. I used sed for it

`sed "s/SERVICE/$service/g"`

The problem is that the variable $service has special characters like ',[,],/,\,",?,` and similar. The sequence of the special characters in $service is not fixed. And whenever there is a special character like " within $service, sed fails to replace it correctly. Is there any solution in which the special characters will not interfere with the sed replacement process. The answer given below did not work for me, it says

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 107: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: Can you provide few examples of `$service` variable's value.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this :

```
sed "s@SERVICE@$(printf '%q' "$service")@g"
```

- `@` is an alternative modifier, that can be any character
- `printf '%q'` escape the given string for the shell :

Ex.

```
$ printf '%q' '*$!'
\*\$\!
```

Comment: But what if the variable `$service` contains the character `@`? Also, `printf '%q'` might answer something with `$'...'`. It only insures that it is reusable by the shell.

Comment: E.g., `printf '%q' 'é'` surprise.